# Trying to normalize data, but got undefined columns selected error in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a dataset contains a variable nr.employed. Its numeric.
I am normalizing it in using code

markting_train_dim_deleted =

```
"","custAge","profession","marital","schooling","default","contact","month","campaign","previous","poutcome","cons.price.idx","cons.conf.idx","euribor3m","nr.employed","pmonths","pastEmail","responded"
    "1",0.486842105263158,"1","3","7","2","1","8",0,0,"2",0.389321901792677,0.368200836820084,0.806393108138744,5195.8,999,0,"1"
    "2",0.342105263157895,"2","2","1","1","1","4",0,0,"2",0.669134840218243,0.338912133891213,0.980729993198821,5228.1,999,0,"1"
    "3",0.315789473684211,"10","2","4","1","2","7",0,0,"2",0.698752922837102,0.602510460251046,0.95737927907504,5191,999,0,"1"
    "4",0.486842105263158,"5","1","1","2","1","4",0.0256410256410256,0,"2",0.669134840218243,0.338912133891213,0.981183405123555,5228.1,999,0,"1"
    "5",0.215870043275927,"1","1","7","1","1","7",0.102564102564103,0.166666666666667,"1",0.26968043647701,0.192468619246862,0.148945817274994,5099.1,999,1,"1"
    "6",0.381578947368421,"2","2","1","1","2","7",0,0,"2",0.698752922837102,0.602510460251046,0.95737927907504,5191,999,0,"1"

cnames=c("custAge","campaign","previous","cons.price.idx","cons.conf.idx",
         "euribor3m"," nr.employed","pmonths","pastEmail")
for(i in cnames){
  print(i)
  print(markting_train_dim_deleted[,i])

  markting_train_dim_deleted[,i]=
    (markting_train_dim_deleted[,i]-min(markting_train_dim_deleted[,i]))/
                                    (max(markting_train_dim_deleted[,i]-min(markting_train_dim_deleted[,i])))

}
```

After processing euribor3m it is printing nr.employed, it throws exception

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(markting_train_dim_deleted, , i) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

I have looked at the structure. Its a numeric datatype with no missing values.

output

```
dput(head(markting_train_dim_deleted))

structure(list(custAge = c(0.486842105263158, 0.342105263157895, 
0.315789473684211, 0.486842105263158, 0.215870043275927, 0.381578947368421
), profession = structure(c(1L, 2L, 10L, 5L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"), class = "factor"), 
    marital = structure(c(3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1", 
    "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), schooling = structure(c(7L, 
    1L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
    "6", "7", "8"), class = "factor"), default = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), 
    contact = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1", 
    "2"), class = "factor"), month = structure(c(8L, 4L, 7L, 
    4L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
    "8", "9", "10"), class = "factor"), campaign = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0.0256410256410256, 0.102564102564103, 0), previous = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.166666666666667, 0), poutcome = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), 
    cons.price.idx = c(0.389321901792677, 0.669134840218243, 
    0.698752922837102, 0.669134840218243, 0.26968043647701, 0.698752922837102
    ), cons.conf.idx = c(0.368200836820084, 0.338912133891213, 
    0.602510460251046, 0.338912133891213, 0.192468619246862, 
    0.602510460251046), euribor3m = c(0.806393108138744, 0.980729993198821, 
    0.95737927907504, 0.981183405123555, 0.148945817274994, 0.95737927907504
    ), nr.employed = c(5195.8, 5228.1, 5191, 5228.1, 5099.1, 
    5191), pmonths = c(999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999), pastEmail = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), responded = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("custAge", 
"profession", "marital", "schooling", "default", "contact", "month", 
"campaign", "previous", "poutcome", "cons.price.idx", "cons.conf.idx", 
"euribor3m", "nr.employed", "pmonths", "pastEmail", "responded"
), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You got my downvote because `markting_train_dim_deleted` is not reproducible. If you can provide a reproducible example of your dataset, I will retract my downvote and give you an upvote.

Comment: I have updated the post

Comment: Thanks for your update, but it is in a bad format. Please consider to use `dput` to share your data.

Comment: @Rohit Haritash try `dput(markting_train_dim_deleted)` and provide the result in your question

Comment: I have updated the dput result

Comment: Thanks again for your update. I have retracted my downvote and given you an upvote as I promised. Next time when you ask a question, please provide a reproducible example so you are more likely to get the help you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is simply having `" nr.employed"` (with a space) rather than `"nr.employed"` in `cnames`.

Also, something like

```
markting_train_dim_deleted[, cnames] <- sapply(markting_train_dim_deleted[, cnames], 
                                               function(x) (x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)))
```

would make the normalization easier to read.